# Matrix of linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need a bit of clarification for an assignment question that I have.

Let T: **F**$[t]_n$$\to$**F**$^2$  (where **F**$[t]_n$ represents polynomials of degree n) given by $T(f) = (f(1) , f(2))$.  I am asked to find its matrix with respect to $B={1,t,..,t^n}$ of **F**$[t]_n$.

I'm wondering how to find what $T(1)$, $T(t)$, ... , $T(t^n)$ equal. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also be told what basis of $F^2$ to use. But since it is not given probably we can assume they meant to use the standard basis of $F^2$.

Then $T(t^k)$ means that you input to $T$ the polynomial $f(t)=t^k$. What $T$ does is to take the polynomial $f$ and evaluate it at $t=1$ and $t=2$ and return the this pair of number. So, $T(t^k)=(1^k,2^k)=(1,2^k)$.

If the basis for $F^2$ is indeed the standard basis $e_1=(1,0), e_2=(0,1)$, then we expand $T(t^k)=(1,2^k)=1e_1+2^ke_2$. And then take all those coefficients and put them as columns of a matrix.